# Facebook analytics - web parameters doesn't show data using a certain term

Tags: facebook-analytics

I can't seem to view facebook analytics data for visitors of webpages containing a certain term in the URL.

In facebook analytics, I click:
1. Create new segment
2. Condition -> Web parameters
3. Current domain -> Contains

Here's a screenshot:
[Current domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAr2f.png)

Then I type the part of the URL but it doesn't load any users (0% of total users)

Answer (score 0):

You can use referral URLs to better understand where your key sources of site traffic are coming from. The help documentation is [here](https://www.intern.facebook.com/help/analytics/270003676790742?helpref=search&sr=2&query=referral%20URL).

> **Apply this Segment:** Condition -> "Web Parameters" Select Parameter -> "Referer URL", Condition -> "is any of" Value -> "[Part of the URL you want to segment by]"

Blog post about this feature [here](https://analytics.facebook.com/blog/november-product-update-lifetime-value-reports-time-based-funnels-and-more/).